# Python - Create Shortcut with arguments

Tags: python, win32com

Using win32com.client, I'm attempting to create a simple shortcut in a folder. The shortcut however I would like to have arguments, except I keep getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/Ms/ms.py", line 153, in <module>
    scut.TargetPath = '"C:/python27/python.exe" "D:/Projects/Ms/msd.py" -b ' + str(loop7)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 570, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("Property '%s.%s' can not be set." % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.TargetPath' can not be set.
```

My code looks like this. I've tried multiple different variates but can't seem to get it right. What am I doing wrong?

```
ws = win32com.client.Dispatch("wscript.shell")
scut = ws.CreateShortcut("D:/Projects/Ms/TestDir/testlink.lnk")
scut.TargetPath = '"C:/python27/python.exe" "D:/Projects/Ms/msd.py" -b 0'
scut.Save()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code works for me without error. (Windows XP 32bit, Python 2.7.5, pywin32-216).

(I slightly modified your code because `TargetPath` should contain only executable path.)

```
import win32com.client
ws = win32com.client.Dispatch("wscript.shell")
scut = ws.CreateShortcut('run_idle.lnk')
scut.TargetPath = '"c:/python27/python.exe"'
scut.Arguments = '-m idlelib.idle'
scut.Save()
```

I got AttributeError similar to yours when I tried following (assign list to `Arguments` property.)

```
>>> scut.Arguments = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 570, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("Property '%s.%s' can not be set." % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.Arguments' can not be set.
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the .Arguments member - I was banging my head against this one for an hour now (on python 3.11.4), trying to feed something like `scut.TargetPath = f'"{exe}" {param}'` into the object...

Answer (score 0):

"..TargetPath should contain only [an] executable path." is incorrect in two ways :

1. The target may also contain the executable's arguments.

For instance, I have a file [ D:\DATA\CCMD\Expl.CMD ] whose essential line of code is
    START Explorer.exe  "%Target%"

An example of its use is
    D:\DATA\CCMD\Expl.CMD "D:\DATA\SYSTEM - NEW INSTALL PROGS"

This entire line is the "executable" you are referring to.

1. The target doesn't have to be an "executable" at all. It may be *any* file in which the OS can act upon, such as those file types whose default actions run executable with the files as its arguments, such as :
   "My File.txt"

The "default action" on this file type is to open it with a text editor. The actual executable file run isn't explicit.

Comment: Just want to add that targetPath can also be a folder. It will then create a shortcut for the folder.