# Python, create shortcut with two paths

Tags: python

im trying to create shortcut with 2 paths on a computer or flash drive , for this i use this code

```
shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
        shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(usbname+i+".lnk")
        shortcut.Targetpath=r'"f:\tx.txt" "f:\lll"'
        shortcut.save()
```

but this code return an error which is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ashraf/PycharmProjects/first/usb.py", line 27, in <module>
    shortcut.Targetpath=r'"f:\tx.txt" "f:\lll"'
  File "C:\Users\Ashraf\PycharmProjects\first\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 581, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("Property '%s.%s' can not be set." % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.Targetpath' can not be set.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

any help ?

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586599/python-create-shortcut-with-arguments ?

Comment: i try but didn't work, the second path "f:\111" is folder not executable